# Log Analysis in Python

Tags: python, logging

For our internal monitoring process, I want to find out how many exceptions have taken place on a particular day. We want to extract the information from the log file of our application (Pylons project).

I want to do this in Python itself. I am aware that I can write a script which will do the offline processing on the log for counting the number of exceptions (and possibly other information related to the exception as well).

I want to ask whether there is already some library which I can use to do log file analysis in Python or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why aren't you using log2mail (http://people.debian.org/~enrico/log2mail/), logcheck (http://logcheck.org/), why you want to reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had a similar situation and found the [logtools](https://github.com/adamhadani/logtools) Python package for the job. I used it for analyzing a Tomcat6/Solr log file.

Copy log from server and install *logtools* in a virtualenv:

```
mkdir /tmp/logwtf
cd /tmp/logwtf
scp server:/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.2012-02-03.log ./catalina.log
virtualenv --system-site-packages --distribute .
. bin/activate
pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/adamhadani/logtools.git#egg=logtools'
```

Summarize search request traffic:

```
qps -r'^(.*?) org\.apache\.solr\.core\.SolrCore execute' \
    -F '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p' \
    -W900 \
    --ignore \
    <catalina.log
```

All server activity between 1:10 and 1:20 PM:

```
qps -r'^(.*? 1:1.:.. PM) ' \
    -F '%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p' \
    -W15 \
    --ignore \
    <catalina.log
```

*logtools* includes additional scripts for filtering bots, tagging log lines by
country, log parsing, merging, joining, sampling and filtering, aggregation and
plotting, URL parsing, summary statistics and computing percentiles.  See the the [package's GitHub page](https://github.com/adamhadani/logtools) for more
information.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional info, like a sample log would be nice. Generally speaking you can always use the powerful re library that work with regular expressions.

[Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[re Library](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

So yeah for general problems re is always a good possibility...

If you post a sample log I can see if I find anything that fits better to ur problem.